# Unable to run pg_buffercache_pages() function

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

I am trying to explore `pg_buffercache` extension and facing error while using `pg_buffercache_pages()` function.
Errors are as follow :

```
test=# SELECT pg_buffercache_pages();
ERROR:  return type must be a row type

test=# SELECT * FROM pg_buffercache_pages();
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM pg_buffercache_pages();

                      ^

-- taken from .sql file of regress test
test=# SELECT * FROM pg_buffercache_pages() AS p (wrong int);
ERROR:  incorrect number of output arguments
```

I have confirmed that I am logged in as a superuser, meanwhile I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find how to run this function.

Comment: As the docs say, use the pg_buffercache view.  Or look at the definition of that view, if you really want to for some odd reason, and see what it does.

Comment: Yes I have used pg_buffercache view but still wondering how can I use pg_buffercache_pages function? :/ Or is it not possible to use it directly?

Comment: As I said, look at the view definition.  It shows you exactly how to use the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is not intended to be used directly, but via the `pg_buffercache` view. If you look at the definition of that view, you will see how it is intended to be called:

```
\d+ pg_buffercache 
                             View "public.pg_buffercache"
      Column      │   Type   │ Collation │ Nullable │ Default │ Storage │ Description 
══════════════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════════
 bufferid         │ integer  │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
 relfilenode      │ oid      │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
 reltablespace    │ oid      │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
 reldatabase      │ oid      │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
 relforknumber    │ smallint │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
 relblocknumber   │ bigint   │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
 isdirty          │ boolean  │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
 usagecount       │ smallint │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
 pinning_backends │ integer  │           │          │         │ plain   │ 
View definition:
 SELECT bufferid,
    relfilenode,
    reltablespace,
    reldatabase,
    relforknumber,
    relblocknumber,
    isdirty,
    usagecount,
    pinning_backends
   FROM pg_buffercache_pages() p(bufferid integer, relfilenode oid, reltablespace oid, reldatabase oid, relforknumber smallint, relblocknumber bigint, isdirty boolean, usagecount smallint, pinning_backends integer);
```

The reason for that error is that the function is defined to return `SETOF record`, so you have to specify the columns returned by the function when you call it.